# Yii relations with condition on current model

Tags: php, yii

My question is how to build this relation in Yii model:

The table ledger:

```
|id|target_type|target_id|amount|
```

sample data would be like:

```
|1|shop|20|100.00|
|2|member|30|99.50|
```

as you can see, I am using the target_type as an indicator of which table to link to, while target_id is the id of the linked foreign table.

I tried this but not working

```
'shop' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'shop', 'target_id', 'condition'=>'target_type=shop'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with workaround like:

```
return array(
            'shop' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Shop', 'target_id'),
            'member' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Member', array('target_id'=>'user_id')),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'shop' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Shop', 'target_id', array(
            'condition' => 'ledger.target_type = :type',
            'params' => array(':type'=>'shop')
        )),
    );
}
```

Comment: "Try " and code only answers are not good answers as they fail to explain what the problem was and how this resolves it.

Comment: I tried but error returned: 'Property "CHasOneRelation.0" is not defined.'